# Check if $span\{b_1+b_2+b_3,b_3+b_2+b_1,b_3\}\cap span\{b_1+b_2,b_1-b_2\}$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ is a basis of vector space $V$. Check if $span\{b_1+b_2+b_3,b_3+b_2+b_1,b_3\}\cap span\{b_1+b_2,b_1-b_2\}$ is a subspace of $V$. If it is, find its dimension and one basis.

What is the procedure for checking if $span\{b_1+b_2+b_3,b_3+b_2+b_1,b_3\}\cap span\{b_1+b_2,b_1-b_2\}$ is a subspace of $V$?

Comment: You have $b_1+b_2+b_3$ and $b_3+b_2+b_1$, which are the same. Is that what you meant?

Comment: A span of vectors is always a subspace, and the intersection of subspaces is always a subspace.

Comment: @Travis, But how to prove it?

Comment: @msitt, That is the problem statement. I don't know if it is a mistake or not.

Comment: Use the definition of intersection and check each of the subspace conditions. For example, suppose $W, W'$ are subspaces of $V$. Then, if $x, y \in W \cap W'$, then $x, y \in W$ and so, since $W$ is a subspace, $x + y \in W$. Likewise, $x + y \in W'$, and so by definition, $x + y \in W \cap W'$, and hence the intersection $W \cap W'$ is closed under addition. Now, check the other two subspace axioms.

Comment: @Travis, How to find dimension and a basis of intersection (vectors $b_1,b_2,b_3$ are not given explicitly, so how to find dim and basis)?